# How to get cell number or row number in the filtered results

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have applied Autofilter and the row numbers  are displayed as
1 3 5 7.
I want to fetch data from cell G1, G3, G5, G7 and copy it and paste it in a differemt sheet. I am a beginner in VB script. I am not able to understand how to proceed to write the code for this. This didplay of filtered results will vary everytime.

Comment: The `.SpecialCells` property of the range object will allow you to select only the visible cells in the range.  You can then copy/paste that range in VBA.  Not sure about vbscript, though.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use VBScript and not VBA? This is not the same! Correct your tags if you meant VBA.